# Calculate percentages of a binary variable BY another variable in R

Tags: r

I want to summarise the percentage of people that have been treated BY region.

I have created a dummy dataset for this purpose:

```
id <- seq(1:1000)
region <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"),c(200,200,200,200,200))
treatment <- rep(seq(1:2), each=4)
d <- data.frame(id,region,treatment)
```

How would I find out (a) the total number of people in each region (I presume I would use length for this purpose) and (b) the percentage of people who had treatment 1 (as oppose to 2) BY region?

I will have NAs for some of the IDs, so if this could be incorporated in the code from the outset, that would be appreciated.

I have used ddply in the past to summarise a continuous variable (i.e. the mean) but am struggling when using a factor variable.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you're struggling with?

Comment: Just a comment regarding rep (not related to your answer): Instead of writing c(200, 200, 200, 200, 200), you might as well use rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), each = 200). Answer to your question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use data.table:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(d)[,.(.N,prop=sum(treatment==2)/.N),
         by=region]
   region   N prop
1:      A 200  0.5
2:      B 200  0.5
3:      C 200  0.5
4:      D 200  0.5
5:      E 200  0.5
```

Comment: What is this: `.(.N,prop=sum(treatment==2)/.N)`? In the `data.table` documentation, it says `symbols ‘.SD’, ‘.BY’, ‘.N’, ‘.I’ and ‘.GRP’ may be used in the ‘j’ expression`. So is it possible to construct further "dot" expressions?

Answer (score 4):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(region) %>% summarize(NumPat=n(),prop=sum(treatment==1)/n())
```

What we do here is group by region and then pipe it to summarize by the number of patients in each group, and then calculate the proportion of those patients that received treatment 1.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this can be very easily (and fast!) done with `table` and `prop.table`:

```
prop.table(table(d$treatment, d$region))
```

This gives you the percentages of each cell. If you want to get row- or column-wise percentages, you want to make use of the `margin` parameter in `prop.table`:

```
prop.table(table(d$treatment, d$region), margin = 2) # column-wise
prop.table(table(d$treatment, d$region), margin = 1) # row-wise
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's how you can do it using `ddply()` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(d[!is.na(d$id),],.(region),summarize,
      N = length(region),
      prop=mean(treatment==1))
#   region   N prop
# 1      A 200  0.5
# 2      B 200  0.5
# 3      C 200  0.5
# 4      D 200  0.5
# 5      E 200  0.5
```

This assumes that you want to deal with the `NA` values in `id` by removing the observation.

Comment: What's your reason for still using `ddply/plyr`?

Comment: @Heroka I guess I haven't fully embraced pipes yet.  In particular, I haven't yet found a convenient moment to train myself to use the necessary functions to make `dplyr` work (like `group_by` and `mutate`).

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. For what it's worth, I found Data.table a lot easier getting used to.